# SQL Server - Create new database without model tables

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2016, is it possible to create a new (empty) database without including any tables from the model system DB?

Comment: short answer - no. perhaps an alternative is to create a backup of your desired "blank" database and restore it. ultimately, you are attempting to work-around the idea of the model database and how it is used. reconsider your customized additions to model?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, short answer: I don't want them there.  I've inherited this database which has been using models for years to create new DBs.  I want to go away from that system, but that's going to be a longer-term effort.  Meanwhile, I'm trying to add in a DB to hold monitoring data.

Comment: Use another instance to create a new "blank" database and then backup&restore it in your instance.

Answer (score 2):

No, `CREATE DATABASE` has no switch to say "don't inherit from `model`."

The easiest workaround is to create an empty database on a different instance of SQL Server that:

- is running the same version of SQL Server
- has no user objects or other customizations to the `model` database that you don't want here

Back up that database, and restore it here (probably need `WITH MOVE` to put the files in the right place).

There are other workarounds, too, but they're more work. For example, you could create the database, let all the objects from `model` get created, and then generate dynamic SQL to drop the tables:

```
USE the_new_database_name;
GO

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
    DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + N';'
  FROM sys.tables AS t
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(t.[object_id], 'IsMSShipped') = 0;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

It can get a little more complex if you have dependencies between tables, since you may have to drop them in a specific order (or [drop all foreign keys first](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3347/drop-and-recreate-all-foreign-key-constraints-in-sql-server/)).

Then repeat for procedures, functions, etc. (You could make a single query from `sys.objects` that generates the drops for all object types, but I think the first workaround above negates that effort.)